# How to override nested css class attributes?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following two `scss` files, and I'm trying to change an attribute that is set when I import an already built component. The first file is the css I'm changing, and the second is the css I'm pulling from. I can't change the second file without messing up the component already built, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify this one attribute...

```
.button-edit {
   
   .imported-button {
      width: 200px;
   }
}
```

```
.imported-button {
   width: 300px;

   .imported-button-color {
      color: red;
   }
}
```

I have figured out how to change the width through the first code block I've shown above, but how would I change the color from red to blue, for example? I've tried...

```
.button-edit {
   
   .imported-button {
      width: 200px;

      .imported-button-color {
         color: blue;
      }
   }
}
```

... but that doesn't change anything for me. Appreciate the help!

Edit: The Javascript being used is structured like...

```
<BoxButton className='button-edit'>
   <div>
      <p>Press here</p>
   </div>
</BoxButton>
```

where the `Button` component has the css attributes in the `.imported-button` class

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in your code, why did you write **className** in the html code?

```
<Button className='button-edit'>
   <div>
      <p>Press here</p>
   </div>
</Button>
```

you should just write class

```
<Button class='button-edit'>
   <div>
      <p>Press here</p>
   </div>
</Button>
```

Second, you have a problem arranging the elements within the scss code, as you want the blue color to activate when its parent class is deleted! How do you want this to be done? This command cannot be implemented because you are asking the language to break its programming to implement your goal

To solve this problem, you have to remove the blue color class from inside the dev whose class you want to delete, so that it becomes as follows

```
.button-edit {
   
   .imported-button {
      width: 200px;
   }
  
  .imported-button-color {
    color: blue;
  }  
}
```

Now we come to JavaScript:

1- We make variables that carry the father div and p

```
let checkDiv  = document.querySelector(".button-edit div")

let checkDivP = document.querySelector(".button-edit div p")
```

2- We make a function on the button so that it contains two conditions

```
document.querySelector(".button-edit").addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  if( checkDiv.className === "" )
    {
      checkDiv.className = "imported-button";
      
      checkDivP.className = ""
    }
  
  else
    {
      checkDiv.className = "";
      
      checkDivP.className = "imported-button-color"
    }
})
```

- first condition

```
if( checkDiv.className === "" )
{
  checkDiv.className = "imported-button";

  checkDivP.className = ""
}
```

If the class is empty, add the width class and delete the color class

- second condition

```
else
{
  checkDiv.className = "";
      
  checkDivP.className = "imported-button-color"
}
```

If the width class exists, delete it and add the color class

The final result / https://codepen.io/emozlove/pen/JjpjmQR

Comment: I think it seems confusing because I didn't include the code I've actually written. This is just a rewrite of the sections I'm working with and what my issues are. Regarding your first comment, I'm not sure why I use className I guess, but it hasn't given me issues with everything else I've written. The code block I included at the end was Javascript as well, not HTML. The <Button> component is a custom built component, and not the one that comes with HTML

Comment: You mean you have two scss files? The first contains the imported-button class, and the second contains the imported-button-color class?

Comment: Or do you mean you have two css files?

Comment: As for the className, it is very normal for you not to see an error, because html is a descriptive language and not a programming language, and accordingly, it does not have a direct deal with the console so it is natural that nothing appears to you, but when you use a technique such as pugjs, it may appear to you wrong but where? in cmd

Comment: I see. Yes, the first two code blocks are both scss files. The first one seen is the one I'm editing, and the second one seen is the styling from the imported component I'm using, which I cannot change/delete/etc

Comment: Well, as far as I know, scss files are converted into a single css file. If you rely on that when creating the files, it is normal that you have one css file and not more than one file, or am I wrong?

Comment: Is the file folder like this? https://i.imgur.com/07uxGKJ.png

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. I only just recently started using scss files. And no, they are structured a bit differently. There are two folders within the same outer folder. Those two folders are different components, and the first scss file goes in the first folder, while the second scss file goes into the second folder (if that makes sense). The files within the first folder are all related, and similarly, the ones in the second folder are all related. However, I need to grab classes from the second folder into the first (the one I'm editing). Sorry if this is super confusing lol

Comment: I think you mean layout and pages folders, if this is what you mean, layout usually contains some formats that you want to repeat inside the first file, what you are trying to do is to deal with scss files directly through the browser and this is not Right, because the browser actually contains a css file and not scss files, so the end result in the browser is that the first element is inside the second element, so you have to apply the same solution that I gave you

Comment: One more thing, since you are at the beginning, first master the scss technique and then start delving into it